# Discord.py User nickname changing

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have been trying to make myself a bot for my `ArmA 3` unit, and upon doing so I have tried to create an `Enlisting` command, which changes the users existing Nickname within the server to the one that they enlist with (Their `ArmA` soldier name). But I am having some trouble figuring out how to do this. I'll leave my code down below for you to look at and hopefully figure out a solution :

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

Client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "+.")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("ToLate Special Operations Reporting For Duty")
    await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name="By Slay > $enlist", type=3))
    print("For more information: Please contact Slay on twitter @OverflowEIP")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.upper().startswith('+.ENLIST'):
        client.change_nickname(message.content.replace('changeNick', ''))

client.run('token')
```

Answer (score 2):

[`change_nickname`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.change_nickname) is a coroutine, so you have to `await` it.  You're also not really using `commands` properly. You should be defining separate coroutines for each command and decorating them with the `client.command` decorator. (You also don't need `Client`, `commands.Bot` is a subclass of `discord.Client`)

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.utils import get

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "+.")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("ToLate Special Operations Reporting For Duty")
    await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name="By Slay > $enlist", type=3))
    print("For more information: Please contact Slay on twitter @OverflowEIP")

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def enlist(ctx, *, nickname):
    await client.change_nickname(ctx.message.author, nickname)
    role = get(ctx.message.server.roles, name='ARMA_ROLE') # Replace ARMA_ROLE as appropriate
    if role: # If get could find the role
        await client.add_role(ctx.message.author, role)


client.run('token')
```

`enlist(ctx, *, nickname)` means we accept commands like

```
+.enlist apple
+.enlist bag cat
+.enlist "dog eat"
```

and will assign those users (the person who called the command) the nicknames

```
apple
bag cat
"dog eat"
```

Comment: If you could also help me out on something else. I am trying to make the command give a role upon entering it into the discord server, could you be of any help? +1 for helping anyways.

Comment: @Slay I edited my answer.  Please ask if you have more questions.

Comment: This answer is now out-dated, the way to do this now is with the [discord.Member.edit](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=nick#discord.Member.edit) coroutine.