# How would I make a command that changes a user's nickname when used? (discord.py-rewrite)

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to create a command for my bot that allows users to change their nickname. I've tried the answer stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49458646) but I get a 'client is not defined' error and when I redefine in within the file itself, it returns a 'client has no 'change_nickname' member' error. The intended usage is supposed to be something like `t!callme Jack` and the user that used the `t!callme` command would have their nickname set to 'Jack'. Does anyone know how I could go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Now if you wanted to change the author of the messages nickname, then all you have to do is add the following:

```
member = ctx.message.author
await member.edit(nick="whatever your heart desires")
```

member is set to the author of the message, and then we tell the bot that the author of the message (or 'member') will change their nickname to 'whatever your heart desires'.
Make sure that the bot has permission to Manage Nicknames, or else this command will not work and it will give you a '403 FORBIDDEN' error.

It should look something similar like what I provided below:

```
@bot.command()
async def callme(ctx):
    member = ctx.message.author
    await member.edit(nick='Nickname wanted')

    #This line is used just to keep chat nice and tidy :)
    await ctx.message.delete()
```

Comment: So I threw this into my code, and it doesn't return any errors when called, but the nickname is not being changed.