# Need advice about discord.py bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, xcode, discord, discord.py

Writing my first bot. I'm trying to make a bot that will change the username and role of a member by command.

Example: !setnick [member] [newnick] ; !giverole [member] [role]

I have the role command working great, however I'm getting confused with the change nickname documentation [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v0.16.7/api.html#discord.Client.change_nickname)

```
    @bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def setnick(ctx, nickname):
    await change_nickname(server.get_member, nickname)
    await ctx.send(f"User's nickname has been changed.")
```

The bot runs, but when I enter the command in discord it returns with this error:

```
Ignoring exception in command setnick:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FILEPATH", line 79, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "FILEPATH", line 23, in setnick
    await change_nickname(server.get_member, nickname)
NameError: name 'change_nickname' is not defined

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FILEPATH", line 863, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "FILEPATH", line 728, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "FILEPATH", line 88, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'change_nickname' is not defined
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is probably object you can use methods on. Currently you are invoking undefined function. Maybe something like client.change_nick(*args). I don't know too much about this API but read this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49454787/discord-py-user-nickname-changing

Comment: Firstly, thank you for answering and assisting me. I read that post the other day, it calls for the author's nickname to be changed. I'm confused on how to get discord to realize that I'm trying to change a different users nickname. I'll take another look at it and see if I can modify it. Hmm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`change_nickname` is a function that you invoke from a class, as you can refer to your documentation, you will notice that the function is under a class called [Client](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v0.16.7/api.html#client).
Meaning that you can't just invoke `change_nickname` out of nowhere.

> For example, it is like your `send(string)` method. You can't just invoke it out of nowhere, you need to use a text channel object to invoke it.
>   Hence, the reason why you did `ctx.send()` instead of doing `send()`.

You probably created a client object when you logged into your bot, `yourObjectName = new Client()`. Find it and use it to invoke `change_nickname()` like so:

```
await yourObjectName.change_nickname(server.get_member, nickname)
```

Comment: Ahhh okay I understand now. Thanks!!